# Undefined Reference Error in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, referenceerror

Hey there I transferred some programs to a Linux server and now I am getting an "undefined reference" error and was wondering if you guys could help me out.

my main is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
        Stack istk;
        istk.push(3.4);
        istk.push(4.5);
        istk.pop();
        istk.push(7.1);
        cout << istk.top() << endl;
        istk.pop();
        istk.pop();
        cout << istk.top() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Here is Stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include "Node.h"

class Stack
{
private:
        Node* tos;


public:
        Stack();
        ~Stack();
        int is_empty() const;
        int is_full() const;
        void push(double);
        void pop();
        double top() const;

};

#endif
```

Here is Stack.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

Stack::Stack():tos(NULL) {
}


int Stack::Stack is_empty() const {
        return tos == NULL;
}

int Stack::Stack is_full() const {
        return 0;
}

void Stack::Stack push(double d) {
        Node* newNode = new Node(d);
        if (is_empty()) {
                tos = newNode;
        }
        else {
                newNode->next = tos;
                tos = newNode;
        }

}

double Stack::Stack top() const{
        assert(!is_empty());
        return tos->data;
}

void Stack::Stack pop() {
        assert(!is_empty());
        Node* discard = tos;
        tos = tos->next;
        delete discard;


}
Stack::~Stack()
{
        while (!is_empty()) {
                pop();
        }
}
```

The errors I am getting all have to do with reference errors to Stack functions.

Comment: "Stack.cpp" should `include` "Stack.h"

Comment: How did you compile and run your program?